# jquery tabs with mysql and pgp

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, tabs

I am trying to make tabs that contain information about student,  these information is stored in the database. I want the first tab to show the information of all students. and the the second tab to show the information of the students that thier grade is A and the the third tab to show the information of the students that thier grade is B.

I made this code but just the first tab shows the information of the students but the second and third tabs don't show anything.

what is wrong with the code?

```
<html>
<head>

<title>students table</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="#tabs-1">1</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-2">2</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-3">3</a></li>
</ul>


<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("","","");
if (!$connection)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("", $connection);


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM studentTable");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

?>  

<div id="tabs-1">

<?php 
echo "Student id: '" . $row["id"];
echo "Student name: '" . $row["name"];
echo "Student grade: '" . $row["grade"];
echo '</table>';
}
?>

</div>


<?Php 

$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM studentTable WHERE grade = 'A'");   
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
{
?>

<div id="tabs-2">

<?php 
echo "Student id: '" . $row["id"];
echo "Student name: '" . $row["name"];
echo "Student grade: '" . $row["grade"];
echo '</table>';
}
?>

</div>

<?php  
$result3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM studentTable WHERE grade = 'B'");   
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result3))  
{
?>     


<div id="tabs-3">

<?php 
echo "Student id: '" . $row["id"];
echo "Student name: '" . $row["name"];
echo "Student grade: '" . $row["grade"];
echo '</table>';
}
?>     

</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use mysqli instead of mysql as its outdated and no longer supported by mysql

Comment: Use different variable name for row for each tab like row1 row2 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is because you have your `tabs-#` `<div>` opening tags inside your `while()` loops.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM studentTable");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{  
?>  
<div id="tabs-1">  //this here needs to be above/outside while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
```

This is creating `n` number of `<div id="tabs-1">`,`<div id="tabs-2">`,`<div id="tabs-3">`, without matching closing tags `</div>`, so now `<div id="tabs-2">` & `<div id="tabs-3">` are nested in `<div id="tabs-1">` and jQuery doesn't know which one to bind `tabs` to.

try moving them before the `while()` loops -

```
<div id="tabs-1">
<?php 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM studentTable");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
 ...
}
?>
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
<?php 
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM studentTable WHERE grade = 'A'");   
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
{
...
}
?>   
</div>
<div id="tabs-3">
<?php  
$result3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM studentTable WHERE grade = 'B'");   
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result3))  
{
...
}
?>     
</div>
```

Also, you have `echo '</table>';` at the end of each tab div. May want to remove those if you don't actually have a table.

Answer (score 0):

In your script you are trying to use Jquery's tab method.

```
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});
</script>
```

This is looking in the HTML for

```
<div id='tabs'> 
    You're tabs in here
</div>
```

Assuming that your SQL statments is not returing "NULL" then I would say you're issue is that you named you're div's tab-1, tab-2, tab-3. With ID's. This means that Jquery can't find anything to turn into tab's.

Change your jquery call to something like this

```
 <script>
$(function() {
$( ".tabsclass" ).tabs();
});
</script>
```

and instead of using id's use classes.

```
<div class='tabsclass' id='tab-1'> 
    You're tabs in here
</div>
<div class='tabsclass' id='tab-2'> 
    You're tabs in here
</div>
<div class='tabsclass' id='tab-3'> 
    You're tabs in here
</div>
```

Comment: the OP has the correct html for binding tabs - `<div id="tabs"><ul><li><a href="#tabs-1">1</a></li><li><a href="#tabs-2">2</a></li><li><a href="#tabs-3">3</a></li></ul> ... </div>`